# Make n copies of files in folder and copy them to a specific folders

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, copy-paste, mkdir

i have already edited this question, because probably would useful for someone else,and well , my problematics is the next:

I have hundreds of files, 256 to be exact ,this files are .csv,
and I need to generate a directory/folder with 50 copies for each file,
for example:

```
-file1.csv---->folder_for_file1---->1copy_file1.csv,2copy_file1.csv,3copy_file1.csv........50copy_file1.csv
-file2.csv---->folder_for_file2---->1copy_file2.csv,2copy_file2.csv,3copy_file2.csv........50copy_file2.csv
-file3.csv---->folder_for_file3---->1copy_file3.csv,2copy_file3.csv,3copy_file3.csv........50copy_file3.csv
...
-file256.csv---->folder_forfile256---->1copy_file256.csv,2copy_file256.csv,3copy_file256.csv........50copy_file256.csv
```

What can I use to do this ??, some bash script or some simple ubuntu/linux command, like mk dir?

P.D/P.S.The answer that they have provided me, works very well, but I had a problem with the name of the generated folder, because it's name is the extension of the file and it's not useful for me.

thanks in advance

Comment: At which point are you stuck? Copies are made using the `cp` command. Instead of first making a copy and then moving the file to another place, I would simply copy it to the other directory under a different name. What's the purpose of keeping these steps separate?

Comment: I appreciate your attention, what happens is that I need to generate all those copies of files, folders, but now I have problems renaming each folder,

Comment: Renaming is done using `mv` or `rename`. If you have problems with using these commands, I suggest that you ask a concrete question about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are not very clear. I will answer with some assumptions.

For each file named `file_i` , suppose you want to create a directory named `file_i_folder` for that file under the same path of these files. You can do this via this command:

```
ls | xargs -t -n1 -i mkdir {}_folder
```

Then you want to create copies of each files under their corresponding directories. Since the names of files cannot be duplicated, you may want to give prefixes for copies, e.g. `copy1_file1`. You can do this via this command:

```
ls -p | grep -v / | xargs -t -n1 -i bash -c 'for i in {1..50}; do cp {} "{}_folder/copy${i}_{}" ; done'
```

You can alter the commands to change the format of the names of files and directories at your own will.

Comment: thank you mate, i will to prove this now

Comment: it works perfectly

Comment: @SdtElectronics : I think it would be safer to avoid `ls` and do a `foreach file in *` instead. Of course you would test inside the loop that `file` really refers to a plain file.

Comment: @StdElectronics, I have been trying with this solution, but notice that the file extension is added to the name of the folder, in this case .csv, how can you customize the name of the created folders?, 
it is true that I need to add more data to my original question